# Redirect from /news to /news/

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I was wondering how can I redirect from `/news` to `/news/` in a google friendly manner, because google sees them as 2 different pages.
I'm already using meta canonical url, but how can I do this with the RewriteRule?

```
RewriteRule ^news$ /news.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^news/$ /news.php [NC]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to read this [link](http://enarion.net/web/htaccess/trailing-slash/) I believe it describe and solve your problem.

It suggests to add to .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !example.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/$1/ [L,R=301]
```

In your case, if you want only a simple rule

```
RewriteRule ^news$ ^news/$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^news/$ /news.php [NC]
```